# Py.test fails, but ./manage.py tests works fine

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, pytest, pytest-django

I took over a code base lately and I started by adding Selenium tests and moving to py.test. I like py.test due to the parallelism and other 3rd party packages, but I noticed major issues with py.test.

The code base is a Django stack (1.8 on Python 2.7, pytest-2.6.4, no x-dist at the moment).

1) py.test tests run slower than the normal django test suite (not great, but I can live with that)

2) When I run unittests together with the Selenium tests by executing `py.test`, **some of the unittest fail**. If I run only the unittest with py.test (excluded by using the `@skipUnless` decorator), **everything passes fine**. All tests run also fine when I run (unittest & selenium) with `./manage.py test`.

py.tests are failing (in the run with unittest and selenium) with an odd error that `DoesNotExist: ActionType matching query does not exist.`.

**Is py.test running tests differently than the normal Django test suite?**

**Any suggestions why the unittest fail when I run it together with the Selenium tests?**

The Selenium tests are executed before the failing unit tests, but they hit a very different area of the code (different modules).

Comment: How do you define your test cases which fail?

Comment: I think the way how django and pytest collect test cases is different so your problem might be just order of test cases. Check if they run in the same order, especially parts that manipulate ``ActionType`` model or if it's not too much work try to set explicit order of tests (which is not good practice as testcases should be independent but you might find place where they are not).

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a similar case. The issue was that queries failed to return objects which I expected to exist.

It turned out they should have been created by signal handlers. Those handlers were registered at import time in a signals.py like

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)                                         
def create_email_verification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
```

The signals.py was imported from the [App configs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/) of the respective modules.

It turned out that the app config was never loaded (due to a missing `default_app_config`), but Django loaded signals.py anyway. However when running through py.test the module was not loaded (because it was not imported anywhere else), and the signal handler was thus never registered.

Conclusion: `manage.py test` seems to auto-import some modules, which py.test does not. There might be some code (signal handlers) that is not explicitly imported otherwise.